# Erasing SRAM in STM32L071RZT6 MCU

Tags: sdram

I am new to MCU programming, I use STM32, C language, IAR IDE, HAL. I need to erase SRAM of the MCU STM32L071RZT6 when the "Erase" button is clicked. How can it be done? Will it cause app crash? Can `memset()` be used for that?

Comment: Normally you just write 0's (or some other known value) to the memory. Typically, your code will be in Flash ROM so it can still run after the RAM is erased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your question is badly formulated and that is not what you want, but I will answer what you have asked for.
Yes you can clear **all** your SRAM but you have to do some very careful coding as it will destroy your stackpointer contents. As such you can NOT call another function as the return address will have disappeared, together with the values of all your variables and intialised structures.
If you do use memset() your CPU will start running from address 0 when it tries to return.